# how to make caption in a figure start a new line at left

Tags: captions

I have a big description at times under a figure and the new lines in the caption start at the center instead from the left.How can i fix it?

Comment: Could you provide a MWE in order for us to reproduce your problem and try to solve it?

Comment: The [`caption` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\usepackage[justification=left]{caption}
```

Comment: there is no `left` key for the `justification` option. What you probably wanted to point to was `justification=raggedright`